Theory of truth involving a virtual omniscient being
I think a correct theory of truth would have to involve a correspondence of some kind between the world and the proposition, but there are problems with trying to explain the connection between cognition and the world. It has occurred to me that one way to avoid these problems is to abstract away from the world and instead appeal to a correspondence between a proposition and the knowledge of an omniscient being. Let G be an omniscient being who never lever lies. The sort of theory I have in mind is:
A proposition P is true iff G would agree with the proposition.
Has anyone discussed this sort of theory and/or criticized it? I'm more interested in the analytic tradition. I know you could probably find related stuff among the scholastics or from Leibniz or Berkeley, but I'm looking for later stuff that doesn't have religious overtones, and specifically doesn't require an actual omniscient being, but only a virtual one.
ADDENDUM in response to comments:

What is the problem with just saying that a proposition is true if it corresponds with a fact? A lot of philosophers have a problem with the existence of facts, but that's not my problem with it. My problem is in characterizing a fact in such a way that it possible for it to "correspond" with a proposition. If you say that a fact is an object that is part of the world and not a mental object, then what would it mean for it to correspond with a proposition, which is a concept, a mental object? In what sense would a concept correspond to a part of the world? If you say that a fact is a mental object (as an idealist might do), then you have to deal will all sorts of problems of dealing with facts (such as what the inside of a neutron star is like) that don't seem accessible to perception or any direct human verification, but where it still makes sense to ask whether propositions corresponding to those facts are true or not.

I recognize that there is a flavor of circularity here, but I think the cycle can be broken by appeals to observable facts. When I say that the omniscient being doesn't lie, I mean something like this: the set of propositions that it agrees to are all consistent with each other at a particular time, and any proposition that it agrees to will never prove to oppose what humans can or could observe given any theoretical powers of observation. Basically the idea is to reduce facts to something like Kantian intuitions, but with a mechanism to deal with unobservable facts.



Interesting, can you say more about how this avoids problems and doesn't create different ones? Normally I think of 'virtual' things being templates or ideal versions of something, but they don't actually "do anything". Your idea seems like what is called using an 'Oracle' to answer questions. But I think those are usually thought experiments, because, as Einstein said, "there is no cat". (we can use 'Einstein' as an Oracle for any cool knowledge) Gosh, someone downvoted already? Not me

The law uses fictitious objective standards such as: the person of ordinary skill in the art (patent law) or the reasonable person (tort law). The fictitious omniscient being G represents a supernatural or ideal person who knows whether any proposition P is true or not-true. Even if such fictitious "person" or "being" exists it is true that actual persons must evaluate and determine whether any given proposition P is true or not-true in the context of their respective minds. The fictitious standards in law exist to guide and influence the reasoning process of the triers of fact in a case.

Unless there's a religious or relational component (we propose the being actually exists and has something to say) this just reduces to "a proposition is true iff it is true".

The circularity (neglecting quibbles, like trying to turn lie/agree with truth into a non-dilemma) is in the definition of "lie" and "omniscient". What is a lie? A not-truth. What is omniscience? Knowing all truth. What is a truth? Something an omniscient knows and a non-liar won't lie about.

Pls make into answer @gs

@Rushi I think it would be off topic as put since the question implies a request for published scholarship. I think a good answer would provide references that I don't have for the necessity of a physical referent at the bottom of any definition in order to escape circularity, i.e. "What is X? It's this. What is Y? It's what that guy is doing."

@gs, I've added an addendum in response to your comment. And although I prefer published sources, I'm interested in general critiques as well.

Re addendum, I agree especially with 2, but a hypothetical being generates no observable facts. If a real being always tells the truth, we can point to it: Me Tarzan. You Jane. That guy's words truth.

My personal opinion is that all human claims or questions about reality are either claims or questions about the outcomes of experiments, or meaningless. The inside of a neutron star is in principle accessible to hypothetical experimentation, but if we want specific claims about e.g. the states of other universes, causally prior universes, the stuff on the other side of a Black Hole or cosmological event horizon, or this universe after all experimenters are extinct, we need to posit the existence of a real "G" that we can really ask just to make the claim mean anything in the first place.

We could punt and appeal to what a liar would say is false. At least there is something at stake with a lie.

That could be useful if such a being were demonstrated to exist. Which is a logical impossibility.

@Rushi I tried.

As an aside, I'd call our little tattletale D, not G; after all, D got banned for spoiling G's ruses, didn't he.

I'll bite and make gs's circularity objection into an answer, especially after you said that you are also interested in ad-hoc criticism.

The circularity argument is more of a transfer argument: We don't know what is true, so we offload the — still impossible! — task of discerning true from false to a fictitious being; nothing is gained.
There is also a more "procedural" transfer: Everybody agrees that "the connection between cognition and the world", the problem you try to evade, is not trivial;  but it applies of course to any interaction with G as well.

The transfer argument becomes even more striking if we imagine the fictitious omniscient being G as ourselves with perfect knowledge. Then, "a proposition P is true iff G would agree with the proposition" devolves into "a proposition P is true iff, assuming we knew if it was true, we would agree with the proposition" which is not more than saying "if only we knew" ;-).

If G could only answer "yes" or "no" it would almost certainly answer "no" to any and all theoretical scientific questions because our theories are almost certainly incomplete. For example, it would have said "No" to Newtonian physics laws (which assume instant interaction between distant objects and hence are very fundamentally untrue). Relativity theory likely shares their fate from a more advanced standpoint; it would be preposterous to assume they are the last thing to say about the topic.
If G can say more than yes or no, it would say "hmmmm, well — within the border conditions you can produce it is true, if you exceed them it becomes false." But we knew that.

Because G does not exist and we have no means of simulating it this truth theory is not productive. It has no use.

Last not least, reality itself is the only place that contains all the information there is; any simulation of it (which would have to run in G's reasoning facilities so that it can discern facts existing in reality from non-facts) is necessarily a simplification and hence incomplete. A truly omniscient G can logically not exist, even if we ignore problems of recursiveness (does it simulate itself? Can it answer questions about itself, or about how reality changes because of its answers?) that likely lead to issues like solving the halting problem, undecidable propositions (Gödel) and antinomies (Russell).
Another way to phrase this is to say "G is the universe; if the universe says it's true it's true". Popper would certainly subscribe to that.



Generally good. Except for 4. — G doesn't exist. How so sure? Plato gave the theoretical framework for the form world. Guys like Ramanujan (he's hardly the only inspired creative) seemed to have an unusually broad broadband line to G ! Of course that said, that G is no longer virtual

@Rushi Well, 4 because of 5; also, if it existed (in an operable sense) we'd know.

becomes even more striking if we imagine the fictitious omniscient being G as ourselves with perfect knowledge This entirely trivializes epistemology. Which is after all what the question is around

@Rushi Sorry, I do not understand your "trivializing epistemology" comment. Can you elaborate? (At the least I would claim that it is not more trivial than the question! ;-) )

Yes the question is in a sense trivial once the circularity is apparent. Epistemology is about what and how far we know. If I = G the essential questions of epistemology have collapsed into 1 word Everything!

@Rushi Yes, everything -- that is already part of the premise of the question. It is the question that skirts the epistemological problems (and, to a degree, on purpose); I'm just showing that it is simply ignoring them (as you correctly diagnose), shifted by 1; the shift can be left out, and then it is obvious.

I wish people would accept that we already know about what we can up to the moment and just move along. If we learn something new in 5 minutes, that's just peachy, but we are not there yet. Why would we want to ruin the story by peeking ahead?!?

@ScottRowe A true Zen stance: "Der Weg ist das Ziel", as we say in German ("the route is the destination", or so).

Re 3, Sometimes-mostly-true propositions are pretty easy to truth-ify by adding error bars, probabilities, and domains. If we could use G as a binary search to identify the domains and predictive precision of our theories, it would be a miraculous advance for mathematical physics.

Re 5, David doesn't think that nature and reality are synonymous, and so at least for David there is no logical inconsistency provided that G is not a subsidiary part of nature.

@gs How do you know what David thinks? (I cannot find that in his question.)

@Peter-ReinstateMonica It's not. I know that David is a supernaturalist from his other posts.


Let G be an omniscient being who never lever lies. The sort of theory I have in mind is:


A proposition P is true iff G would agree with the proposition.

This seems like a Theory of Truth based on Expert Opinions and their value as indicators of the truth. The omniscient being in your example represents the "perfect state", but expert opinions can have reliability ranges so simple propositions now have probabilities attached to them.

Who evaluates the reliability of a human expert or the knowledge of an AI? There is no ultimate authority. I have been satified with google search for many years but now when a search query produces an AI Overview I must deliberately discount and ignore that portion of the search results or spend my scarce brain power to question its relevance or validity. I would much rather sort through articles with actual human authors and spend my brain power on that effort. In theory an AI can become more intelligent than any human expert but the community of human experts must evaluate and rank the AI.

Clever AIs, you just can't trust the damn things. Give me a good human liar or idiot any day! :-)

@Scott Rowe I took a graduate level electrical engineering course called Expert Systems way back in 1990. I had to write a paper on Engineering Ethics, so I read Schaum's Outline, which said Ethics is the effort to answer two questions: What is good for life or in life? How should one act to cause the good? Humans ask these two questions and one other core question: Who do I want to be like? We want to be like (or not be like) some character(s) in the drama (e.g., Sidhartha becomes Buddha). I also learned that explicit knowledge, expressed in language, cannot describe implicit human knowledge.

@SystemTheory right, I think people get carried away with this quest for truth, it is basically self-defeating. But it is easier to tell if something works or not (engineering) and whether it is good or not (health). We should solve those fully before trying for something more abstract.

Your post does not deal with the question how to define truth. Instead you ask for a universal method, how to verify general propositions as being true propositions.

Since the turn of falsificationism due to Karl Popper such an
enterprise seems a bit backwards-looking, like reestablishing the
outdated search for final justification in epistemology.
Popper was
a philosopher who criticized the search for such a theory.

From Popper's viewpoint it seems exotic to search for an
omniscient being “G”.
If the virtual classical theistic being “G” did not achieve what you
want, why do you think that a virtual non-theistic being “G” has
a better change to satisfy the requirement?



My proposed definition doesn't even suggest a verification method, much less define one. In fact, that's one off the weaknesses I see in the theory--that it doesn't seem to lead to any verification method.

@DavidGudeman What is the aim of your searched method?

I'm trying to define what it means to say of a proposition that it is true.

@DavidGudeman Don't we have Tarski's definition? He defined decades ago when a proposition is true. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_theory_of_truth

If we can verify something, that is the definition of 'true'. I think we have this old problem licked now...

You say:

I think a correct theory of truth would have to involve a correspondence of some kind between the world and the proposition

and

I'm trying to define what it means to say of a proposition that it is true.

While you're free to interpret theories of truth as right and wrong, many notable philosophers such as Pierce, Dewey, James, Sellars, McDowell, Rorty, Van Fraassen, and a great number of others gravitate towards adequacy. That's because truth-conditional semantics is highly influential in secular philosophy and that carries with it Tarski's semantic theory of truth. As such, T-sentences allow a judgement of truth between a correspondence between the proposition and the subject of the proposition to be left to those wielding the metalanguage which is frequently free to be interpreted in accordance with the intent of the creator of the model. This is because Tarski used incompleteness in the same was as Gödel to argue "that a truth-predicate satisfying Convention T for the sentences of a given language cannot be defined within that language". Thus, we have to bridge from within the language to without, which is the goal of metaphysical grounding.
In simpler language, the truth of a proposition is relative to the nature of the metaphysical grounding (SEP). If one wants to ground propositions in empirical facts derived from the physical world, then one has the correspondence theory of truth (SEP). If one wants to ground propositions in the consistency with other propositions, then one has the coherence theory of truth (SEP). According to the Encyclopedia of Philosophy's entry "Truth", besides the semantic, correspondence, and coherence theories, there are also the identity and disquotational/deflationary accounts of truth which appeal to other strategies besides empirical evidence and rational coherence.
As to appealing to an omniscient being, that was advocated by Augustine and Aquinas (Academia.edu), and today is still a strategy preached by some theologians. For instance, R.C. Sproul was a notable supporter of such a claim. He argues that point in his writings here. The idea that truth originates God is a distinctly theological thesis that has little currency with modern epistemologists who are predominantly secular naturalists. If you're looking for a modern take, it would seem your investigations should start with him.
This is part and parcel of the evolution of what is demarcated as "philosophy" according to Maria Sassi in her The Beginnings of Philosophy in Greece. Thales and Anaximander began reforming thinking by moving cosmogony towards apeiron and away from the narratives of Homer and Hesiod. Thus, philosophers have always been more preoccupied by 'Is there a God?' more than 'What does God think?'. Philosophers who are religious fundamentalists, pietists, and fideists of all stripes quickly move from the first question to the second, but most mainstream professional secular philosophers are comfortable with the range of theories of truth that don't involve divine beings.
Looking at the index of A Companion to Epistemology also produces some additional theories of truth (consensual, redundancy, minimal, etc.) none of which meet the criteria of corresponding with the thinking of a divine being. While the guide doesn't specifically explain why a theory isn't named and included, one might reasonably infer the difficulty lies in the practicality of such a method to ascertain the truth. Even if one fully embraces a divine being, and certainly many professional philosophers are theists of some stripe, knowing what God's truth is is not obvious or simple. If it were, there would be no need for faith, scripture, or divine revelation.
